# MS Access Variable String Search

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to create a query that identifies entries where a long text string does not contain any of a list of substrings.

What I have is...

```
SELECT [other necessary data], [Long text string]
WHERE [Long String] NOT LIKE "*[substring1]*" 
  AND [Long string] NOT LIKE "*[substring2]*" 
  AND [Long string] NOT LIKE "*[substring3]*"
```

This works fine. HOWEVER! I want the list of excluded substrings to be variable, e.g. project 1 excludes substrings 1 and 3, project 2 excludes substrings 2, 3, and 17, etc.

Any suggestions on how to go about doing this?

Comment: Please demonstrate how you have attempted to solve the problem and where you have gone wrong. See how to ask a question http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Is project a column in the table you are selecting from?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some thing like this? Then you would just have to call it, with up to four strings to exclude and use the sql for whatever you are looking to do.

```
Function strsql(ex1 as string,Optional ex2 as string = "", _  
Optional ex3 as string = "", Optional ex4 as string = "") as string
strsql = "SELECT [other necessary data], [Long text string] _  
WHERE [Long String] NOT LIKE " & chr(34) & "*" & ex1 & "*" & _  
chr(34)
If ex2 <> "" then  
strsql = strsql & " AND [Long String] NOT LIKE " & chr(34) & _  
"*" & ex2 & "*" & chr(34)  
End if  
If ex3 <> "" then  
strsql = strsql & " AND [Long String] NOT LIKE " & chr(34) & _  
"*" & ex3 & "*" & chr(34)  
End if  
If ex4 <> "" then  
strsql = strsql & " AND [Long String] NOT LIKE " & chr(34) & _  
"*" & ex4 & "*" & chr(34)  
End if
strsql = strsql & ";"  
End Function
```